# Qt QSSlSocket - SEGFAULT on 'connectToHostEncrypted();'

Tags: c++, qt, ssl, twitch

I am attempting to connect to the Twitch chat server via SSL and I basically copied and pasted some code from the Secure SSL Connection example in QT. When I can `connectToHostEncrypted` it all crashed. Any help is greatly appreciated

Relative code:

```
void MainWindow::secureConnect()
{
    if (!socket) {
        socket = new QSslSocket(this);
        connect(socket, SIGNAL(stateChanged(QAbstractSocket::SocketState)),
                this, SLOT(socketStateChanged(QAbstractSocket::SocketState)));

    connect(socket, SIGNAL(encrypted()),
            this, SLOT(socketEncrypted()));

    connect(socket, SIGNAL(error(QAbstractSocket::SocketError)),
            this, SLOT(socketError(QAbstractSocket::SocketError)));

    connect(socket, SIGNAL(sslErrors(QList<QSslError>)),
            this, SLOT(sslErrors(QList<QSslError>)));

    connect(socket, SIGNAL(readyRead()),
            this, SLOT(socketReadyRead()));
    }
    qDebug() << 2;
    socket->connectToHostEncrypted("irc.chat.twitch.tv", 443);
    QEventLoop loop;
    connect(socket, SIGNAL(connected()), &loop, SLOT(quit()));
    loop.exec();
    qDebug() << 5;
    sendData("PASS oauth:" + TwitchAccessToken);
    sendData("NICK ThatRedstoneGT");
    sendData("JOIN smartguy316");
    sendData("PRIVMSG Hello!");
}
```

Declaration:

```
Public:
QSslSocket *socket:
```

Comment: Is `socket` initialized to `nullptr` in the `MainWindow` constructor?

Comment: @G.M. I edited the code. Go have a look.

Comment: But where do you *initialize* `socket`?  If you don't initialize it to `nullptr` somewhere then when `MainWindow::secureConnect` is called it will, in general, have some non-null value in which case `if (!socket) {` will fail and you will never actually create a new `QSslSocket`.  Can you update the post to show the code for the `MainWindow` constructor(s).

Comment: @G.M. Not too sure. Can you explain?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Putting this as an answer as I'm not sure I've managed to get my point
>   across in the comments.

You have a class `MainWindow` with a member `socket`.  Keeping things to a minimum let's say it's...

```
class MainWindow {
public:
  MainWindow();
  void secureConnect();
  void sendData(QString text);
  QSslSocket *socket:
};
```

Now, I would expect the constructor implementation to look something like...

```
MainWindow::MainWindow ()
  : socket(nullptr)
  {}
```

If you don't initialize `socket` to `nullptr` *before* `MainWindow::secureConnect` is called then it will have some random value.  In which case...

```
if (!socket) {
```

will fail meaning that the block containing...

```
socket = new QSslSocket(this);
```

will never be executed.

By way of a test, can you run your code under a debugger, set a breakpoint on the line...

```
if (!socket) {
```

and check the value of `socket`.  The first time that line is hit `socket` should be null.  Is it?

Comment: Oh I see, actually I missed that I added `MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::MainWindow), socket(0)` But, it says that `QAbstractSocket::connectToHost() called when already looking up or connecting/connected to "irc.chat.twitch.tv"` I updated my code to show my changes in the `secureConnect()` function.

Comment: That suggests you're calling `MainWindow::secureConnect` more than once against the same instance.  Sorry, but you really need to think about your design a bit more.

Comment: Can you provide a link to the example?

Comment: I extracted the barebones of the ssl connection.

Comment: Ok, so the example code in the [link](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtnetwork-securesocketclient-example.html) is pretty basic, and has essentially no error checking.  Hence it also appears to suffer from the issue you are now seeing -- namely ''QAbstractSocket::connectToHost() called when already...''.